# При создании файла на диски выбрасывает Exception

Tags: java, eclipse

```
File file2 = new File("‪‪C:\\Users\\Kuzminchuk_Alexandr\\Desktop\\A\\Test20.txt");
==========================================================
System.out.println(file2.createNewFile());
==========================================================
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at Lesson8_Stream.FileEXP.main(FileEXP.java:33)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"‪‪C:\Users\Kuzminchuk_Alexandr\Desktop\A\Test20.txt"

при копировании пути со свойств папки, каким то образом не понятным между (первой кавычкой и C) стоит два скрытых пробела, если нажать Backspace то чтоб ее удалить надо 3 раза нажать. И из за этого выбрасывало Exception  на синтаксис.

Answer (score 0):

Это должно работать:

```
public void writeFile(String filename, String text)  throws IOException{
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(filename));  // Создаем FileWriter 
        writer.write(text); // Пишем файл
        writer.flush(); // "Отчищаем" FileWriter 
}
```